# Custom Sort based on String length

Tags: javascript, string, sorting

I am trying to sort this data.

My data looks like this:

```
var test =   [
            {label: '41_45', 
            value :14},
            {label: '46_50', 
            value :34},
            {label: '1', 
             value :44},
            {label: '10_15', 
            value :84}
            {label: '3', 
            value :44},
            {label: '6_10', 
            value :94},
            {label: '16_20', 
            value :74},
            {label: '21_25', 
            value :64},
            {label: '26_30', 
            value :44},
            {label: '31_35',
            {label: '4', 
            value :44},
            {label: '5', 
            value :24},
            {label: '36_40', 
            value :444},
            {label: '>50', 
            value :24},
            {label: '2', 
            value :44}
        ];
```

But I want to sort it based on label so that I can get results like this:

```
  var test =   [
            {label: '1', 
            value :44},
            {label: '2', 
            value :44},
            {label: '3', 
            value :44},
            {label: '4', 
            value :44},
            {label: '5', 
            value :24},
            {label: '6_10', 
            value :94},
            {label: '11_15', 
            value :84},
            {label: '16_20', 
            value :74},
            {label: '21_25', 
            value :64},
            {label: '26_30', 
            value :44},
            {label: '31_35', 
            value :4},
            {label: '36_40', 
            value :444},
            {label: '41_45', 
            value :14},
            {label: '46_50', 
            value :34},
            {label: '>50', 
            value :24}
        ];
```

Is there any library or function which I can leverage to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this could be done using the angular filters (as others have mentioned), it can also be done before the view logic, utilizing the JavaScript function [array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). *sort()* can accept an optional function *compareFunction* that can handle sorting the items:

> If *compareFunction* is supplied, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are two elements being compared, then:
>
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b, i.e. a comes first.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.
> - `compareFunction(a, b)` must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.
>     <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)</sup>

To compare the *label* property of each item, which is a string, use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to parse an integer from the strings when comparing the items, like in the code below. Notice *10* is passed as the radix (2<sup>nd</sup> argument) to ensure no strings get parsed as a hex/octal number by mistake.

```
var newArray = test.sort(function(item1, item2) {
    if (parseInt(item1.label,10) < parseInt(item2.label,10)) {
         return -1; //put item2 after item1
    } 
    return 1; //otherwise put item1 after item2
});
```

See a demonstration of this below (click *Run code snippet* to see the results). The conditional logic has been simplified using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```js
var test =
    [{
      label: '41_45',
      value: 14
    }, {
      label: '46_50',
      value: 34
    }, {
      label: '1',
      value: 44
    }, {
      label: '10_15',
      value: 84
    }, {
      label: '3',
      value: 44
    }, {
      label: '6_10',
      value: 94
    }, {
      label: '16_20',
      value: 74
    }, {
      label: '21_25',
      value: 64
    }, {
      label: '26_30',
      value: 44
    }, {
      label: '31_35'
    }, {
      label: '4}',
      value: 44
    }, {
      label: '5',
      value: 24
    }, {
      label: '36_40',
      value: 444
    }, {
      label: '>50',
      value: 24
    }, {
      label: '2',
      value: 44
    }];
var newArray = test.sort(function(item1, item2) {
  return (parseInt(item1.label,10) < parseInt(item2.label,10))?-1:1;
  });
console.log(newArray);
```

---

<sup>1</sup>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to use [loadash sortby](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy)

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 }
];

_.sortBy(users, [function(o) { return o.user; }]);
// => objects for [['barney', 36], ['barney', 34], ['fred', 48], ['fred', 40]]

_.sortBy(users, ['user', 'age']);
// => objects for [['barney', 34], ['barney', 36], ['fred', 40], ['fred', 48]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the view using **`angular`**, you can use orderby with the **`ng repeat`** filter,

**Code:**

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in test | orderBy:'label' ">
    <h1>{{item}}</h1>
  </div>
```

If you want to do it in controller, you can use  $filter,

**Code**

```
$scope.filtered =  $filter('orderBy')($scope.test, 'label');
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope','$filter', function($scope,$filter) {
  $scope.test =
    [{
      label: '41_45',
      value: 14
    }, {
      label: '46_50',
      value: 34
    }, {
      label: '1',
      value: 44
    }, {
      label: '10_15',
      value: 84
    }, {
      label: '3',
      value: 44
    }, {
      label: '6_10',
      value: 94
    }, {
      label: '16_20',
      value: 74
    }, {
      label: '21_25',
      value: 64
    }, {
      label: '26_30',
      value: 44
    }, {
      label: '31_35'
    }, {
      label: '4}',
      value: 44
    }, {
      label: '5',
      value: 24
    }, {
      label: '36_40',
      value: 444
    }, {
      label: '>50',
      value: 24
    }, {
      label: '2',
      value: 44
    }];
   $scope.filtered =  $filter('orderBy')($scope.test, 'label');
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="loginController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in filtered">
    <h1>{{item}}</h1>
  </div>
  <script type=" text/javascript " src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js "></script>
  <script type="text/javascript " src="MainViewController.js "></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue is I want to show 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6-10 , 11-15 so basically based on first letter(int) of string

Answer (score 0):

Feasible Solution will is already suggested by @Sajeetharan . Angular provides you better control over this data which will be efficient as well as very easy to implement.

you can use **filters** from angular js to get the output in time.

```
 <table>
       <tr>
          <td>label</td>
          <td>value</td>
       </tr>
       <div ng-repeat="data in test | orderBy:'label' ">
          <tr>
             <td>data.label</td>
             <td>data.value</td>
          </tr>
       </div>
  <table>
```